# Nuances lost in merge...

Tags: discussion, merging

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8783/resources-to-learn-linux was merged into https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/good-introductory-resources-for-linux/8785, which seems quite reasonable given the headlines. But the older question was:

> Basically what should I know for daily
>   interaction with a linux webserver and
>   what are good resources to learn it.
>
> ( I'd like this to be kind of a faq
>   for good introductory resources to
>   Linux as an OS, so server tips are
>   good, but it shouldn't have to be
>   server only )

whereas the new one was

> What would you professionals recommend
>   a beginner ***do*** to learn how to use this
>   OS to its full potential?

(Emphasis added.)

I'm not complaining about the merge, but I liked the distinction between "give me a list of resources" and "what should I actively do to learn". Anyone have suggestions for how to put that back into the merged question without being too disruptive?

Comment: I just want to point out that I do want to do some rewriting of the original question... it's a bit of the 3rd of it's sort... and I'd kinda like to turn it into a beginner faq of where to start.

Comment: @xenoterracide — sounds good to me. I would like to keep the "How do I get started with Linux" separate from "Give a list of newbie links", though.

Comment: well hopefully resources will be more than just a list of links...

Comment: @xenoterracide — I think lists of links are the likely outcome. Maybe some "try to see if there's a local LUG". Am I crazy in making a "what are resources" / "what should I _do_" distinction?

Comment: possibly. What do you do, also depends on how you want to learn, and in some cases what.